# How to keep text on sceen while scrolling in react

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, scroll

I am working on a very simple website consisting of an image, with some text overlaid on top of it. In some cases, the image may be bigger than the screen, and then the user can scroll. However, I would like the overlaid text to remain on-screen, centered, even when the user scrolls. How can I do this?

Here is a basic idea of my code at the moment:

```
const styles = theme => ({
    main_screen: {
        position: "relative",
        textAlight: "center",
        color: "white",
        height: '100%',
        width: '100%',
        margin: "0",
        padding: "0"
    },
    caption: {
        color: "yellow",
        margin: "1em",
    },
    
    overlayText: {
        position: "absolute",
        width: "100%",
        top: "5%",
        alignItems:"center"
    },

    main_image: {
        maxwidth: "100%",
        maxHeight: "100%",
        objectFit:"cover",
        display: "block",
        margin: "0",
        padding: "0",
        overflow: "scroll"
    },
})


class ExampleSite extends React.Component {

....

    render(){
        return(
            <div id="main-screen" className={classes.main_screen}>
                <img id='target-image' onLoad={this.readDims} className={classes.main_image} src={pano_1} alt={""}/>
                <div className={classes.overlayText}>
                    <Typography className={classes.caption} align="center" > {this.state.instructionText}  </Typography>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`position: fixed;` on the text object is what you want. [MDN - CSS Position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)